# How can i update my form with validation in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

My form validation is not working in Laravel. How can I update my form with validation in Laravel?

You can check my code here-

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id->validate([
        'Name'=>'required',
        'UserName'=>'required',
        'Password'=>'required|min:6',
        'email'=>'required|email',
    ]);

    $updateInfo= Info::findOrFail($id);
    $updateInfo->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $updateInfo->Name = $request->input('Name');
    $updateInfo->UserName = $request->input('UserName');
    $updateInfo->Password = $request->input('Password');
    $updateInfo->save();

    return redirect('/info');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call validate on $request, like this-

```
$request->validate([
    'Name'=>'required',
    'UserName'=>'required',
    'Password'=>'required|min:6',
    'email'=>'required|email',
]);
```

Here is the full code-

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'Name'=>'required',
        'UserName'=>'required',
        'Password'=>'required|min:6',
        'email'=>'required|email',
    ]);

    if (!$validator->fails()) {
        $updateInfo= Info::findOrFail($id);
        $updateInfo->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $updateInfo->Name = $request->input('Name');
        $updateInfo->UserName = $request->input('UserName');
        $updateInfo->Password = $request->input('Password');
        $updateInfo->save();
    } else {
       \Session::flash('error', $validator->messages()->first());

        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }


    return redirect('/info');
}
```

I have added one more condition in the code to handle the validation errors. If validation fails then it will redirect back with your inputs as well as the validation error messages. Make sure you have error session flash in your blade views to show the errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is best way , i can keep on track on query and other exceptions by putting it in try catch block

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try{
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name'          => 'required',
                'UserName'      => 'required',
                'Password'      => 'required',
                'email'         => 'required|email',
            ]);
            if($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect()
                    ->route('path_to_edit_form')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
            }
            Info::where('id',$id)->update([
                'user_id'    => $request->get('user_id'),
                'Name'       => $request->get('Name'),
                'UserName'   => $request->get('UserName'),
                'Password'   => $request->get('Password'),
            ]);
            return back()->with([
                'alert_type'    => 'success',
                'message'       => 'User info updated successfully.'
            ]);
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return back()->with([
                'alert_type'    => 'danger',
                'message'       => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```